# Laravel - How to set fallback url. If a url does not exist, redirect to some default page

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing

I am using Laravel 5.4. And facing problem to redirect to some default view if user enter a url which does not exist. How can this be setup with Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/resources/views/errors/` create a file called `404.blade.php`

Everytime a route does not exist, Laravel will return HTTP Status 404 and serve that view.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view and set this code in app/Exception/Handler.php

```
/**
 * Render an exception into a response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
   if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
   {
     return response()->view('missing', [], 404);
   }
   return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Set this use to get it working :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
```

see more [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-do-i-create-a-custom-404-error-page)